# C++ Heap Sort Implementation

Tags: c++, heap-sort

Just checking if I could still do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::size_t getParent(std::size_t n)
{
    return (n - 1) / 2;
}

template<typename I>
void heapify(I begin, I end)
{
    std::size_t size    = std::distance(begin, end);
    for(std::size_t loop = 1;loop < size; ++loop)
    {
        std::size_t current = loop;
        std::size_t parent  = getParent(current);
        while(current != 0 && *(begin + parent) < *(begin + current))
        {
            std::swap(*(begin + parent), *(begin + current));
            current = parent;
            parent  = getParent(current);
        }
    }
}

template<typename I>
void heapPop(I begin, I end)
{
    I   last = end - 1;
    std::swap(*begin, *last);

    std::size_t size    = std::distance(begin, last);
    std::size_t current = 0;
    while(current < size)
    {
        std::size_t child1  = current * 2 + 1;
        std::size_t child2  = current * 2 + 2;
        std::size_t goodChild = current;

        if (child2 < size)
        {
            goodChild   = (*(begin + child1) > *(begin + child2)) ? child1 : child2;
        }
        else if (child1 < size)
        {
            goodChild   = child1;
        }
        if (*(begin + current) < *(begin + goodChild))
        {
            std::swap(*(begin + current), *(begin + goodChild));
            current = goodChild;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
}


template<typename I>
void heap_sort(I begin, I end)
{
    heapify(begin, end);
    while(begin != end)
    {
        heapPop(begin, end);
        --end;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int  data[] = {6,5,3,1,8,7,2,4};
    heap_sort(std::begin(data), std::end(data));
    std::copy(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I think we all do this eventually. :-) http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2012/12/heaps-and-heapsort.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The `heapify` and `parent`functions can be avoided:**

You just need the sinking logic that you already implemented. But instead of having current always starting at 0 you can set it as a parameter:

```
template<typename I>
void sink(I begin, I end, std::size_t index)
{

    std::size_t size = std::distance(begin, end);
    std::size_t current = index;
    while (current < size)
    {
        std::size_t child1 = current * 2 + 1;
        std::size_t child2 = current * 2 + 2;
        std::size_t goodChild = current;

        if (child2 < size)
        {
            goodChild = (*(begin + child1) > *(begin + child2)) ? child1 : child2;
        }
        else if (child1 < size)
        {
            goodChild = child1;
        }
        if (*(begin + current) < *(begin + goodChild))
        {
            std::swap(*(begin + current), *(begin + goodChild));
            current = goodChild;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Due to the fact that the elements [image] are leafs you can ignore them, so you just need to apply sink 
[image] 
times to build the heap:

```
template<typename I>
void heap_sort(I begin, I end)
{
    std::size_t size = std::distance(begin, end);
    for (int i = size / 2 - 1; i > -1; --i) 
    {
        sink(begin, end, i);
    }
    while (begin != --end) 
    {
        std::swap(*begin, *end);
        sink(begin, end, 0);
    }
}
```

**Alternative sink implementation:**

IMO this implementation is more concise:

```
template<typename I>
void sink(I begin, I end, std::size_t index)
{

    std::size_t size = std::distance(begin, end);
    std::size_t current = index;
    std::size_t child;

    std::less<decltype(*begin)> less;

    while ((child = 2 * current + 1) < size)
    {
        I itr_child   = begin + child;
        I itr_current = begin + current;

        if(child < size - 1 
            && less(*itr_child, *(itr_child + 1))
        {
            ++itr_child;
        }

        if (!less(*itr_current, *itr_child))
        {
            break;
        }
        std::swap(*itr_current, *itr_child);
        current = child;
    }
}
```

Comment: alternative sink function is much better, i have only one suggestion, if you changed `*(itr_child + 1) > *itr_child` to some thing like`!Pred(*(itr_child + 1), *itr_child)`, it will allow the user to define his predicative expressions in template parameters. i have modified your sink function to be recursive with default predicate `std::less`. live demo http://cpp.sh/636i

Comment: oops should have used less there aswell. You are right that will be better :).

Comment: Nice alternate solution, but assignment in expression `(child = 2 * current + 1)` is bound to always raise the question: "was that really the intention or did they mean `==`". I would personally avoid that.

Comment: @glampert You got a point there, I guess the trade of readability for conciseness is not really worth it in that case.

Answer (score 1):

i inspired of @MAG alternative solution, i re-implemented it in recursive way  by providing template parameters. as following:

```
template <typename RandomAccessIterator, typename Distance, typename Compare>
void adjust_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, Distance len, Distance current, Compare comp)
{
    if(current >= len) return;

    Distance child = current * 2 + 1;

    if (child >= len) return;

    if ((child + 1 < len) && !comp(first[child + 1], first[child]))
        child++;

    if (!comp(first[current], first[child])) return;

    std::swap(first[current], first[child]);

    adjust_heap(first, len, child, comp);
}
```

for sort the heap. first we need to make the heap and then sort it like so:

```
template <typename RandomAccessIterator, typename Compare =
std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type>>
void heap_sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp = Compare{})
{
    using Distance = typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::difference_type;

    // make heap
    const Distance size = last - first;
    for (Distance i = size / 2 - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        adjust_heap(first, size, i, comp);
    }

    // sort heap
    for (Distance i = size - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        std::swap(first[0], first[i]);
        adjust_heap(first, i, Distance(0), comp);
    }
}
```

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <functional>

template <typename RandomAccessIterator, typename Distance, typename Compare>
void adjust_heap(RandomAccessIterator first, Distance len, Distance current, Compare comp)
{
    if (current >= len) return;

    Distance child = current * 2 + 1;

    if (child >= len) return;

    if ((child + 1 < len) && !comp(first[child + 1], first[child]))
        child++;

    if (!comp(first[current], first[child])) return;

    std::swap(first[current], first[child]);

    adjust_heap(first, len, child, comp);
}

template <typename RandomAccessIterator, typename Compare =
std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::value_type>>
void heap_sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, Compare comp = Compare{})
{
    using Distance = typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::difference_type;

    // make heap
    const Distance size = last - first;
    for (Distance i = size / 2 - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        adjust_heap(first, size, i, comp);
    }

    // sort heap
    for (Distance i = size - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        std::swap(first[0], first[i]);
        adjust_heap(first, i, Distance(0), comp);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int  data[] = {6,5,3,1,8,7,2,4};
    std::copy(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";

    heap_sort(std::begin(data), std::end(data));
    std::copy(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";

    heap_sort(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::greater<int>());
    std::copy(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```